# Storage Performance

Tags: php, performance, storage, debian

I want to enable users to upload images & videos to a website. 
Question is now, shall I just drop all the files in one folder or make a folder e.g. for each user?
(Of course it would be easier to find)

Does it make a difference in the performance?
Is it any difference in the access rate?

thanks

Comment: Are you familiar with [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) ?

Comment: Are you familiar with file-system limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're dealing with many files, it's a common principle to distribute the files across multiple (sub-) directories. This is because if a directory contains too many directories and files, the file-system needs to do more work. Distributing the files helps then.

But this always depends on the underlying-file-system you use as a database. You need to look which one you use and then check the features it supports and which limits are given.

On the application layer, you should model file-access and handling so you can change how your application stores the files later on w/o rewriting your whole application.

Comment: Yes, I already have a alias system for file-access. I guess the Server is using ext3 or similiar file system. The files on the disk will have a mysql database entry where exactly they are located.